# Batch file moves to location in argument

Tags: batch-file, arguments, required

Thanks to [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) the batch file below will check for illegal characters, replace them with a dash, search subdirectories and require a location argument, but when it's run it takes you to the directory you specify in the argument. I want to stay in drive/folder the batch file is run from. (ex: rename.bat c:\test, this will take you to c:\test after batch file runs)

```
@@echo off
IF "%~1"=="" goto Continue 
pushd %1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%I in (*) do (
    set "file=%%~nxI"
    if "!file:~0,1!"=="~" (
        set "file=-!file:~1!"
    )
    for %%d in (# %%) do (
        if not "!file!"=="!file:%%d=!" (
            set "file=!file:%%d=-!"
        )
    )
    if not "!file!"=="%%~nxI" (
        echo %%~fI -^> !file!
        ren "%%~fI" "!file!"
    )
)
Exit /B
:Continue
@echo You need drive and directory at end or this batch file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `FOR /R` loop, add `POPD` to "undo" the directory change performed by the respective `PUSHD` command.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %1

for /r %%I in (*) do (
...
)

REM Revert back to the original directory.
POPD
ENDLOCAL

Exit /B
:Continue
```

Comment: I tried adding POPD, but it didn't have any affect.

Comment: @cwhitmore - I tweaked the structure a bit so the `PUSHD` command comes _after_ the `SETLOCAL`. Additionally, I added the respective `ENDLOCAL`.